# riscv-gnu-toolchain downloading everytime while rebuilding process

Tags: riscv

Hello I am trying to add an instruction in RISCV. Each time I try to change the assembler in gnu-toolchain by editing files in binutils, I understand that I have to rebuild it. But do I need to run the build.sh script always? Because every time I do that, I see some data downloading while I have already downloaded it once. If downloading is not required then what command do I actually run to rebuild it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the build.sh script that builds gcc calls into the gcc makefile.  Within that makefile, it downloads the main tree and copies over the relevant risk-v stuff.  If you want to stop the downloading, then look into the top-level Makefile/Makefile.in and grep for "url".  You should see the Makefile rule that is fetching the data at the url and untarring it.